# How to insert a time gap of 2 seconds between execution of two statements in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time-wait

I am building a simple 2D game using Unity.In my C# script,i want to insert a gap of 2 seconds between two consecutive statements.

```
void OnGUI()
{


    GUI.Button (new Rect(400,40,45,45),"text1");
    // time gap statement
    GUI.Button (new Rect(800,40,45,45),"text1");

    }
```

It means that i want a button to be created and displayed and after that wait for 2 seconds before next button is created and displayed on screen.
Any easy way to do this??

Comment: @Derek I assume you've forgotten to add "don't even try to use" before your `Thread.Sleep(2000)`. Otherwise it is pretty bad suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OnGUI` is executed approximately every frame to draw the user interface, so you can't use delays like this.  Instead, conditionally draw the second element based on some condition that becomes true, e.g.

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Button (new Rect(400,40,45,45),"text1");
    if (Time.time > 2) {
        GUI.Button (new Rect(800,40,45,45),"text1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb bro! Short and simple. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to do a delay, but that's not really appropriate since you are displaying this in OnGUI.

Try something like this:

```
public float secondButtonDelay = 2.0f; // time in seconds for a delay

bool isShowingButtons = false;
float showTime;

void Start()
{
     ShowButtons(); // remove this if you don't want the buttons to show on start
}

void ShowButtons()
{
    isShowingButtons = true;
    showTime = Time.time;
}

void OnGUI()
{
     if (isShowingButtons)
     {
         GUI.Button (new Rect(400,40,45,45),"text1");

         if (showTime + secondButtonDelay >= Time.time)
         {
             GUI.Button (new Rect(800,40,45,45),"text1");
         }
     }
}
```